# Cannot see the name of my app and neither the back button

Tags: android-studio

i am trying to get the name of my app to show on top of the screen as well as a back button but im not able to get either of them.

This is my manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TextPatternApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MyTextApp"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

And this is my output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZSWA.png)

what can i do to get the back button and the app name ?

Comment: Drop your `themes.xml` and your layout's xml to help you more.

Comment: Hello :)) i got the issue , after watching a video i just removed the NoActionBar from my themes.